# Symfony2, compress an image file

Tags: symfony, upload

So, i have an action for upload an image on my server like :

```
            if( ( $file = $request->files->get('file')) !== null) {
                $date = new \DateTime();
                $fileName = $this->getUser()->getId() . '_' . $date->getTimestamp();
                $file->move('uploads', $fileName);
            }
```

I need, just before move(), compress my image to reduce the size. Is there something for that with Symfony2 ?

How can i do that simply ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you search on Google? https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle does the trick!